# Translating "there is no number between two consecutive numbers"

Tags: logic, logic-translation

> There is no number number strictly between two consecutive number.

Is my translation $$∀x ∈ Z | ∀y ∈ Z | ¬∃z ∈ Z \;(z<y ∧ z>x ∧ y=x+1)$$ correct?

Is $$∃x | ¬∃n ∈ Z \;(n<x<n+1) $$ also correct? I assume that they are just two different ways to say the same thing.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: I appreciate that, one more inquiry, would it be also to say that (∃x ¬∃n ∈ Z (n<x<n+1)) ? I assume that they are just two different ways to say the same thing.

Comment: The second form doesn't make sense to me. I would write $\not \exists x | \forall n \in Z (n < x < n+1)$ since $\exists x$ doesn't make sense if you're trying to state no such number exists.

Answer (score 2):

> > There is no number between two consecutive numbers.
>
> Is my translation $$∀x ∈ Z | ∀y ∈ Z | ¬∃z ∈ Z \;(z<y ∧ z>x ∧ y=x+1)$$
> correct?

Yes. Equivalent translations of "there is no integer strictly between two consecutive integers" include $$∀(x,y,z){∈}\mathbb Z^3    \;(x<z<y \implies y\ne x+1)$$ and $$∀(x,y,z){∈}\mathbb Z^3    \;(y=x+1\;\land\;z>x\implies z\not<y).$$

> Is $$∃x ∈ Z | ¬∃n ∈ Z \;(n<x<n+1) $$ also correct? I assume that they are
> just two different ways to say the same thing.

Is there a typo? This suggestion says that there is some integer such that no consecutive pair of integers envelope it.